# Fetch data from site Page by Page & go through sub links

Tags: php, arrays, list, fetch

URL : http://www.sayuri.co.jp/used-cars

Example : http://www.sayuri.co.jp/used-cars/B37753-Toyota-Wish-japanese-used-cars

Hey guys , need some help with one of my personal projects  , I've already wrote the code to fetch data from each single car url (example) and post on my site

Now i need to go through the main url : sayuri.co.jp/used-cars  , and :

1) Make an array / list / nodes of all the urls for all the single cars in it , then run my internal code for each one to fetch data , then move on to the next one

- I already have the code to save each url into a log file when completed (don't think it will be necessary if it goes link by link without starting from the top but will ensure no repetition.

2) When all links are done for the page , it should move to the next page and do the same thing until the end ( there are 5-6 pages max )

I've been stuck on this part since last night and would really appreciate any help . Thanks

My code to get data from the main url :

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.sayuri.co.jp/used-cars/');
// echo $content;
```

and

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($content);
    //echo $dom;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you already know this since you say you've gotten data from the car entries themselves, but a good point to start is by dissecting the page's DOM and seeing if there are any elements you can use to jump around quickly. Most browsers have page inspection tools to help with this.

In this case, `<div id="content">` serves nicely. You'll note it contains a collection of tables with the required links and a `<div>` that contains the text telling us how many pages there are.

Disclaimer, but it's been years since I've done PHP and I have not tested this, so it is probably neither correct or optimal, but it should get you started. You'll need to tie the functions together (what's the fun in me doing it?) to achieve what you want, but these should grab the data required.

You'll be working with the DOM on each page, so a convenience to grab the DOMDocument:

```
function get_page_document($index) {
    $content = file_get_contents("http://www.sayuri.co.jp/used-cars/page:{$index}");
    $document = new DOMDocument;
    $document->loadHTML($content);
    return $document;
}
```

You need to know how many pages there are in total in order to iterate over them, so grab it:

```
function get_page_count($document) {
    $content = $document->getElementById('content');
    $count_div = $content->childNodes->item($content->childNodes->length - 4);
    $count_text = $count_div->firstChild->textContent;

    if (preg_match('/Page \d+ of (\d+)/', $count_text, $matches) === 1) {
        return $matches[1];
    }

    return -1;
}
```

It's a bit ugly, but the links are available inside each `<table>` in the contents container. Rip 'em out and push them in an array. If you use the link itself as the key, there is no concern for duplicates as they'll just rewrite over the same key-value.

```
function get_page_links($document) {
    $content = $document->getElementById('content');
    $tables = $content->getElementsByTagName('table');
    $links = array();

    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        if ($table->getAttribute('class') === 'itemlist-table') {
            // table > tbody > tr > td > a
            $link = $table->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild->getAttribute('href');
            // No duplicates because they just overwrite the same entry.
            $links[$link] = "http://www.sayuri.co.jp{$link}";
        }
    }

    return $links;
}
```

Perhaps also obvious, but these will break if this site changes their formatting. You'd be better off asking if they have a REST API or some such available for long term use, though I'm guessing you don't care as much if it's just a personal project for tinkering.

Hope it helps prod you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your help . I can't get the 3rd part working :  Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object ------------------This line : $link = $table->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild->getAttribute('href');

Comment: I posted the entire php code i'm using for testing in the pastebin file above

Comment: I'm not surprised that parts of it aren't working. You'll probably want to do some checking to make sure my code is valid. Test and see how far along that chain you can get -- is $table->firstChild valid? is $table->firstChild->firstChild? 

Like I said, I haven't worked in PHP in years.